# Windows 7, Microsoft Excel 2010. Formula Function help for 2 lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have created 2 'list' cells that each contain 5 options in each list, the first list is a word, plus a number next to each word. The second list is a word plus a letter. I wish to then have a third cell that takes the selection from each cell and produces an outcome in the form of a different word and number. There are 25 different outcomes. At the moment I simply have a 3rd column with 25 options that you manually select, but I would like this to be automated to save time and to reduce human error. Is there a specific formula/function I can use? Is this even possible? Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please explain how the selections from the two lists should generate the "different word and number".  Are the word and number contained in the two lists? How would the formula choose them, randomly? An example of the two selections and the new outcome would help.

Comment: sorry, yes I appreciate its not clear. The results of both selections would produce a specific outcome. The number and letter would form part of the outcome along with a further categorisation. I guess a list of 25 would have to be preloaded?

Comment: I see. And yes, you would have to preload the outcomes. See Sir Adelade's answer. His 2D lookup is a great idea. You'd need a 5x5 grid, with one selection determining the row and the other determining the column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate the two selected options, you can use a formula like:

```
=A1 & " " & B1
```

If you want the result to be looked up from a list of 25 options, you'll need to write the data down in a sheet somewhere to look up first. Using a 2D matrix would make the lookup easy:

```
   A          B        C         D        E           F
1            Val_A     Val_B             Select_1:   Option_1
2 Option_1   Dog      Circle             Select_2:   Val_B
3 Option_2   Squid    Square             Answer:     Circle
```

In this example, cells F1 and F2 are your selection dropdowns. F3 is the answer, which would have the following formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$C$3,MATCH(F1,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH(F2,$B$1:$C$1,0))
```